# version control in mongoose and nodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, version-control, mongoose

In one of my project there are lot of update request (PUT request) fire every second . My Backends is NodeJs ,ExpressJs is middleware and mongoDB is database . I just think of a situation that , what would happens if N update request trigger on a same object at same time . sorry for being a newbie , but even after searching a lot about it , I am unable to find the best way to handle this phenomena .

please suggest me the best way to handle this situation . thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

nothing is ever 'the same time'. it would be a bad idea to have a database where two requests sent at the same time would throw an error.

instead, mongodb will handle the two requests in sequence. whichever request reaches mongodb first will update, then the second request will update again.

Answer (score 0):

Node will take care of the request asynchronously using the event loop with mongoose.So you don't have to worry until you have written correct asynchronous non blocking code.